# How to render component which store in object for Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, filter

I have few components import into this file. It will render it depending if match the roles.

As example, we have **"A"** role in this user. It should render *AdminDashboard* and *CustomerDashboard*. How to do in this way if I save details in **DashboardComponents** Object and try to render component if filter matched my condition.

I will pass into the **props** into the component too.

```
import AdminDashboard from "../AdminDashboard";
import ProjectDashboard from "../ProjectDashboard";
import CustomerDashboard from "../CustomerDashboard"

const DashboardComponents  = [
  { id: 1, component: AdminDashboard, roles: [ "A" ] },
  { id: 2, component: ProjectDashboard, roles: [ "C", "D" ] },
  { id: 3, component: CustomerDashboard, roles: [ "A", "B" ] },
]

const DashboardComponent = () => {


  /**
    I tried use React.cloneElement for component Dashboard which from DashboardComponents.
    it can't be render.
  **/


  return (
   /** render the match DashboardComponents with props data={ data } in here **/
  )

}
```

I knew we can do it in this way. but it look messy for me if I have 10 Dashboard.

```
import AdminDashboard from "../AdminDashboard";
import ProjectDashboard from "../ProjectDashboard";
import CustomerDashboard from "../CustomerDashboard"

const DashboardComponent  = () => {
  return (
     <>
      {
        condition === "A" && (
           <AdminDashboard data={ data } />
        )
      }
      {
        condition === "A" && (
           <ProjectDashboard data={ data } />
        )
      }
      {
        condition === "A" && (
           <CustomerDashboard data={ data } />
        )
      }
     </>
   )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
const AdminDashboard = ({data}) => {

  return (
    <div>
      AdminDashboard: {data}
    </div>
  )
}

const ProjectDashboard = ({data}) => {

  return (
    <div>
      ProjectDashboard: {data}
    </div>
  )
}

const CustomerDashboard = ({data}) => {

  return (
    <div>
      CustomerDashboard: {data}
    </div>
  )
}

const DashboardComponents  = [
  { id: 1, component: AdminDashboard, roles: [ "A" ] },
  { id: 2, component: ProjectDashboard, roles: [ "C", "D" ] },
  { id: 3, component: CustomerDashboard, roles: [ "A", "B" ] },
]


export default function App() {
  const condition = 'A';
  let dash_role = DashboardComponents.filter(dc => dc.roles.indexOf(condition) > -1);

  return dash_role.map(
    dr => {
      const Comp = dr.component;
      return (
        <Comp 
            key={dr.id}
            data={`data_props ${dr.id}`}
        />
      )
    }
)
}
```

And if you want to use React.cloneElement:

```
// add onPress for who you want
const ProjectDashboard = ({data, onPress}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      ProjectDashboard: {data}
      <button onClick={() => onPress(data)}>Click!</button>
    </div>
  )
}
export default function App() {
  const condition = 'A';
  let dash_role = DashboardComponents.filter(dc => dc.roles.indexOf(condition) > -1);

  const onPress = data => {
    alert(data);
  }
  return dash_role.map(
    dr => {
      const Comp = dr.component;
       const child = (
        <Comp 
          key={dr.id}
          data={`data_props ${dr.id}`}
        />
      );

      return React.cloneElement(child, { onPress});

    }
)
}
```

Comment: Thank sharing your reactjs knowledge

Answer (score 0):

As your role "A" have 2 dashboards so I am supposing you only want to access one dashboard at time. So I have written code of it and you have to pass the role name in find function it will fetch the component for it.

```
import AdminDashboard from "../AdminDashboard";
import ProjectDashboard from "../ProjectDashboard";
import CustomerDashboard from "../CustomerDashboard"


const DashboardComponents  = [
  { id: 1, component: AdminDashboard, roles: [ "A" ] },
  { id: 2, component: ProjectDashboard, roles: [ "C", "D" ] },
  { id: 3, component: CustomerDashboard, roles: [ "A", "B" ] },
] 
const DashboardComponent  = () => {
  const find=(role)=>DashboardComponents.filter((item)=>item.roles.includes(role));

  return (
     <>
       {find('A')?.[0]?.component(data)}   {/* pass data as props to that component */}
     </>
   )
}
```